# Setting Tint in appcompat for XML drawables

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have a fairly simple selector with two states. A light gray shade for normal and a dark gray for pressed. Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <inset android:insetLeft="8dp"
        android:insetTop="8dp"
        android:insetRight="8dp"
        android:insetBottom="8dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/widget_gray_dark" />
                <padding android:left="8dp"
                    android:top="8dp"
                    android:right="8dp"
                    android:bottom="8dp" />
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
    <item>
        <inset android:insetLeft="8dp"
            android:insetTop="8dp"
            android:insetRight="8dp"
            android:insetBottom="8dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/widget_gray_light" />
                <padding android:left="8dp"
                    android:top="8dp"
                    android:right="8dp"
                    android:bottom="8dp" />
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Now I want to add the android's tint feature to it. Setting the `tint` attribute to any widget with this selector on pre-lollipop devices has no effect. I am using app-compact and according to its [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), it should work. Maybe I am not using it properly.

How can I set the tint?

Comment: have you went through FAQ section of blog?

Comment: I have. How does it answer my question?

Comment: It mentions cretin situation where your tint may not work.

Comment: Yeah. This is not one of them.